# Create variants table like shopify

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-tags-input

Hello i'm using jQuery tag input library to create variants option like shopify for example each product can have a specific options like color size... 
I have 3 inputs fields and each input contain a variable number of tags that the user will enter on the interface, how can i multiplicate the number of tags that i have in the first  input(color) with the number of tags that i have in the second line ( size )

For example
    Number of color tags X number of size tags

This is an example : 
[image]

this is my jQuery code :

```
$('.tagline').on('change', function(){
    for(i = 0; i < $('.tagline').length; i++){
        // multiplicate line 1 width the line 2
    }
});
```

This is my Html Code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control tagline tokenfield" value="">
```

i want to generate a table like that : 
[image]

Comment: If you have created one please share the code.

Answer (score 1):

you can make this table by Cartesian product like what Ive used in angularjs

```
$scope.createVariation = function() {
        var tagsArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.optionsList.length; i++) {
            tagsArr[i] = $scope.optionsList[i].tags.split(',');
        }

        const cartesianProduct = (...arr) => {
            return arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
                return acc.map(el => {
                    return val.map(element => {
                        return el.concat([element]);
                    });
                }).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
            }, [
                []
            ]);
        };

        var variationList = [];

        if ($scope.optionsList.length == 1) {
            variationList = cartesianProduct(tagsArr[0]);
        }
        if ($scope.optionsList.length == 2) {
            variationList = cartesianProduct(tagsArr[0], tagsArr[1]);
        }
        if ($scope.optionsList.length == 3) {
            variationList = cartesianProduct(tagsArr[0], tagsArr[1], tagsArr[2]);
        }

        $scope.makeVariationTable(variationList);
    }

    $scope.makeVariationTable = function(variationList) {
        $scope.variationListArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < variationList.length; i++) {
            $scope.variationListArray.push({
                'variant': variationList[i],
                'price': '',
                'sku': '',
                'barcode':''
            });
        }
    }
```

which $scope.optionsList is the array of options that user has defined.

$scope.optionsList = [{name:'size',tags:'10,10.5,11,11.5'},{name:'color',tags:'red,blue'}]